# Google Cloud SQL Read Replica Failing to replicate

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have created a new read replica from the GCP Cloud SQL Console, using the create read replica option

I am getting following error after creation of replica, replica instance is creating successfully but the replication not starting as expected.

Here is the error message I am getting in the error log.

> "2020-05-05T05:11:30.747872Z 4 [ERROR] Slave I/O for channel '': error
>   connecting to master 'cloudsqlreplica@172.17.112.4:3306' - retry-time:
>   60  retries: 1, Error_code: 2003"

- binlog is already enable on master.
- Database version is MySQL 5.7
- Auto storage increase is enabled
- Automated backups are enabled
- Point-in-time recovery is enabled

Please let me know if anyone came across this issue and if you know how to solve this problem.

Comment: As an Occam's Razor... at least one backup was created AFTER you enabled binlog, but before you tried to create the replica?

Comment: Also, for connectivity, are you using public IP or private IP for the primary instance? As a gut-check, (Error 2003 often points at an improperly formatted CIDR network issue) get the IP address of your replica instance, and add it as an authorized network on your primary instance.